# Linear algebra - Property of an exterior form

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, symplectic-geometry

It is true the following statement?

> Let $E$ be a real vector space with $\dim E=n$. If
>   $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis of $E$ and $\{e^1,\ldots,e^n\}$ is the
>   dual basis of $E^\star$, then for every $\omega\in \Lambda^rE^\star$
>   (i.e. $\omega$ anti-symmetric covariant tensor) there exists
>   $a\in\mathbb R$ such that: $$\omega=a\, e^1\wedge\ldots\wedge e^r,$$
>   where $\wedge$ is the exterior product of $E$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should firstly state what have you tried to solve the problem. Nevertheless, such a statement is true only if $r = n$. Counterexample for $r < n$: let $\omega$ be given by $$ \omega = e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge \dots \wedge e^r + e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge \dots \wedge e^{r+1}. $$ Then $\omega$ is an $r$-form, i.e. $\omega \in \Lambda^r E^{\star}$ but cannot be written as $$\omega = a e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge \dots \wedge e^r$$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ since $e^1 \wedge e^2 \wedge \dots \wedge e^r$ and $e^2 \wedge e^3 \wedge \dots \wedge e^{r+1}$ are linearly independent elements of the basis of $\Lambda^r E^{\star}$

Comment: In fact even $e^2 \wedge \dots \wedge e^{r+1}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: That is something we can agree on :)